# php slashes expression

Tags: php, expression, backslash

I have a html like this

> <div><font
>   color="green">ABC</font>A'ssd"fsdf</div>

i need to change the above as

> <div><font
>   color=\"green\">ABC</font>A'ssd"fsdf</div>

that is \" appears only in html component , not in text data.

in php how?

Comment: learn html and css before php, then learn how Stack Overflow works and accept answers to your questions

Comment: Just indent your code by 4 spaces and it will appear as-is! No need to replace all `<` with `&lt;` etc.

Comment: how can i accept answers to my questions give me link

Comment: Also, what you're asking for is highly unusual. What do you want to use this for?

Comment: If you have such a requirement, you're probably doing something wrong.  Why do you want that?

Comment: start by reading the FAQ linked at the top of every page.

Comment: You've been a member of SO for over a year and *now* you're asking?!!

Comment: i am a member for one year but did not use this site for appox 1 year

Comment: excellent, now you can start on learning semantically correct HTML

Comment: i know html but i want to do the above thing as follows                   var a = "<div><font color=\"green\">ABC</font>A'ssd"fsdf</div>";        in Javascript. how can do? here some errors are present

Comment: if you knew html you would not be using <font>

Comment: @msaif what the others are saying is that this code snippet makes no sense in an HTML context. Unless you're trying to put this string into a JS variable that is quoted with double quotes. Let alone the use of `<font>` tags in your code

Comment: I only like to add this in Javascript not in HTML this was my purpose but I didn`t write this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to do the above thing as follows `var a = "<div><font color=\"green\">ABC</font>A'ssd"fsdf</div>";` in Javascript.

If you want to do this, you also want to escape the `"` in the text, or it will break your Javascript syntax just the same. The answer is to encode it in the JSON format:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
    <div><font color="green">ABC</font>A'ssd"fsdf</div>
HTML;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var a = <?php echo json_encode($html); ?>;
</script>
```

And seriously, don't use `<font>`. Learn CSS. :)

Comment: @msaif What are you trying to do there? Also, that has little to do with what's going on in this question...